# К глаголу "не доедет" к названию города возможен ли предлог "в"?

Tags: предлоги

Можно ли использовать выражение "Поезд не доедет в Москву" и не довезет...или только "к Москве"?

Answer (score 0):

Нормальное стилистическое употребление - "не доедет до [Москвы]".
Думаю, этого следует придерживаться во всех случаях.
"Не доедет в ... " режет слух, но это не критичная ошибка, смысл понятен.
А вот "не доедет к ..." это уже ошибка скорее грамматическая. Никак не могу согласиться, что с вашим "надо только". Вот "только" так и не надо.

Comment: Вот в стихотворной строчке можно сказать? "Сядешь в звенящий вагончик трамвайный
(Ближе к окну, если вдруг повезет). 
Он не доедет во Франкфурт-на-Майне
И до Венеции не довезет."

Comment: Ох-хо-хо... Не видевши всего стихо целиком, воздержусь от резких оценок. Но если из общих соображений. Поэту все можно. Его читатели оценивают, а не филологи... Но, честно говоря, я бы постарался как-то поправить строчку. Да и не только её. Рифма "повезет" - "довезет" не из шикарных...

Comment: И ещё: трамвай всё-таки не едет, а идёт.